# Jenkins running as a service restarts by itself after upgrade from 2.303.2 to 2.319.3

Tags: jenkins, upgrade, jvm

I upgraded Jenkins (running as a service) from version 2.235.5 to 2.303.2 (by just replacing .war file and restarting the service), which seemed to work pretty stable. Before doing it, I upgraded Java from OpenJDK 8 to OpenJDK 11, which was the prerequisite for Jenkins upgrade. I tried to upgrade even to 2.319.3 or to 2.332.3 and I was able to log in to GUI with my AD credentials after upgrade, however there are some issues which cause Jenkins to restart by itself from time to time when using these 2 releases, so for now I downgraded it back to 2.303.2.

The question is why is this happening ?

When there was Jenkins 2.319.3 or 2.332.3 running, I could have observed the following messages in Jenkins log:

> […] 2022-06-01 11:10:26.854+0000 [id=30] INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization 2022-06-01 11:10:27.484+0000 [id=33] INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins 2022-06-01 11:10:42.114+0000 [id=29] INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Prepared all plugins 2022-06-01 11:10:42.160+0000 [id=36] INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started all plugins 2022-06-01 11:10:42.227+0000 [id=35] INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Augmented all extensions 2022-06-01 11:10:46.047+0000 [id=30] INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config loaded 2022-06-01 11:10:47.060+0000 [id=33] INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config adapted 2022-06-01 11:10:47.060+0000 [id=33] INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Loaded all jobs 2022-06-01 11:10:47.066+0000 [id=36] INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Configuration for all jobs updated 2022-06-01 11:10:47.110+0000 [id=57] INFO hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Started Download metadata 2022-06-01 11:10:47.168+0000 [id=57] INFO hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$1: Finished Download metadata. 49 ms 2022-06-01 11:10:47.398+0000 [id=29] INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization 2022-06-01 11:10:47.524+0000 [id=23] INFO hudson.WebAppMain$3#run: Jenkins is fully up and running 2022-06-01 11:11:48.936+0000 [id=16] WARNING o.j.p.workflow.job.WorkflowRun#checkouts: JENKINS-26761: no checkouts in startTestEsign #43 2022-06-01 11:11:48.997+0000 [id=16] WARNING o.j.p.workflow.job.WorkflowRun#checkouts: JENKINS-26761: no checkouts in startTestEsign #24 2022-06-01 11:11:53.601+0000 [id=25] INFO winstone.Logger#logInternal: **JVM is terminating. Shutting down Jetty** Running from: /storage/jenkins/jenkins.war webroot: System.getProperty(“JENKINS_HOME”) 2022-06-01 11:11:55.083+0000 [id=1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @977ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog 2022-06-01 11:11:55.327+0000 [id=1] INFO winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file […]

OS is RH 7.9, I don’t know how exactly this Jenkins was installed - it was done by someone else but ‘rpm -qa | grep -i jenkins’ command doesn’t show anything and ‘yum list | grep -i jenkins’ shows only this:

```
python2-jenkins.noarch 0.4.16-2.el7 1cvmware_EPEL_EPEL_7Server
python2-jenkins-job-builder.noarch
python36-jenkins.noarch 0.4.16-2.el7 1cvmware_EPEL_EPEL_7Server
```

What may be the issue ? Please help with it.

Thanks in advance!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

With systemd, we had an issue with a low default value for TimeoutStartSec at /lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service. This caused the Jenkins process to restart repeatedly when systemd was starting the Jenkins service.